# McNemar exact test

Tags: r, statistics, contingency, statistical-test

I have the following data:

```
> Performance = as.table(rbind(c(794,150),c(86,570))
> Performance
    A   B
A 794 150
B  86 570
```

I perform an Exact McNemar test in R, obtaining the following result:

```
> library(exact2x2)
> mcnemar.exact(Performance)

    Exact McNemar test (with central confidence intervals)

data:  Performance
b = 150, c = 86, p-value = 3.716e-05
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.329228 2.300979
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.744186
```

I understand the results, nevertheless, someone could explain to me how the confidence interval is computed?

Comment: sorry, please avoid screen shots.. else it's a bit time consuming to reproduce what you have. is it from exact2x2 ?

Comment: ok, sorry, yes it is!

Comment: Just curious if your study had 1600 participants with paired results (1st survey and 2nd survey) or 800 participants with 2 surveys (resulting in 1600 data points)?  The contingency table for the second case would add to 800 rather than 1600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it more in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exactMcNemar.pdf) and also check out the [code](https://rdrr.io/cran/exact2x2/src/R/mcnemar.exact.calc.R). Using this wiki picture for illustration:

[image]

The odds ratio is b / c, which in your case works out to be `150/86 = 1.744186`. You can construct a binomial confidence interval around the proportion of successes, treating b as success and number of trials to be b + c.

In the code, they used this bit of code to calculate:

```
library(exactci)
CI = binom.exact(150,86+150,tsmethod = "central")
CI

data:  150 and 86 + 150
number of successes = 150, number of trials = 236, p-value = 3.716e-05
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5706732 0.6970596
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.6355932
```

You have the upper and lower bound of b, then odds ratio is p / 1- p :

```
CI$conf.int/(1-CI$conf.int)
[1] 1.329228 2.300979
```

The vignette for binom.exact states:

> The 'central' method gives the Clopper-Pearson intervals, and the
>        'minlike' method gives confidence intervals proposed by Stern
>        (1954) (see Blaker, 2000).

So this is one of the [many methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) of estimating a binomial confidence interval.